# vb.net vs C# lambda expression

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I am facing a strange problem when parsing a very simple lambda expression.

In C#, i have this

```
class Class1
{
}

class Class2 : Class1
{ }

class Invoker
{
    public System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Class1>> GetExpression()
    {
        return () => new Class2();
    }
}
```

This, as expected returns an expression with NodeType = New

In VB.NET, i have

```
Public Class Class1

End Class

Public Class Class2
    Inherits Class1

End Class

Public Class Invoker
    Public Function GetExpression() As Expression(Of Func(Of Class1))
        Return Function() New Class2()
    End Function

End Class
```

This returns a lambda expression with NodeType = Convert (?????)

I suppose it has to do with conversion from Expression(Of Func(Of Class2)) to Expression(Of Func(Of Class1))

I tried playing with project properties like Option Strict... I can't get it to work in VB.

Is there a way i can get the correct lambda expression in VB? I need this to implement an EnterpriseLibrary TraceListener. The base class calling the GetExpression() validates the lambda and tries to cast it to System.Linq.Expressions.NewExpression (which fails in VB since it is a UnaryExpression because of the Convert).

Thanks

Renaud

Answer (score 0):

When I run both pieces of code in Visual Studio (V2008, 64bit Console Application,  3.5 framework), they both return an expression with `NodeType == ExpressionType.Lambda`

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention i am using VS 2010 with .Net 4.0